# To brace or not to brace: case statement block

Tags: scala, coding-style

I am asking a specific question here (not an opinion):  is there any scala style guide recommendation for the following "case o:" addressing whether the (optional) use of braces were to be avoided or if either with/without were both acceptable:

```
 def mycase(x : Int) = {
      x match {
      case 0 =>
        println("zero")
        println("blah zero")
      case 1 =>
        println("one")
      }
```

I was not initially convinced it would even work (thought it might do a fall through): but it does the correct breakout:

```
scala> mycase(0)
zero
blah zero
```

I specifically want to know if there were a canonical answer on this (not "I prefer" , etc.).  E.g. for java, Sun had stated long ago that placing the initial curly brace for a method may happen either on same or next line - both are acceptable. is there such a clear answer in this case?

**UPDATE** An answer provided below by @acjay provides a link to the style guide. Inside here is a specific blurb.

from  http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/control-structures.html#curlybraces

> case - Omit braces if the case expression fits on a single line.
>   Otherwise, use curly braces for clarity (even though they are not
>   required by the parser).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Scala's style guide about this http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/control-structures.html#curly-braces seems **changed**, where it says

> case - Always omit braces in case clauses.

Actually, when editing in IntelliJ, it will remind user of unnecessary braces around case block.

Thus, to avoid introducing further confusion to users, please make a correction to the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 5):

The [Scala Documentation Style Guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/control-structures.html#curlybraces) says:

> case - Omit braces if the case expression fits on a single line.
>   Otherwise, use curly braces for clarity (even though they are not
>   required by the parser).

Therefore, the correct format is:

```
def mycase(x : Int) = x match {
  case 0 => {
    println("zero")
    println("blah zero")
  }
  case 1 => println("one")
}
```

Separate from the question, but with pertinence to the example given, [the declarations section](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html#body) of the style guide mentions the preferred formatting for the `match` as such:

> Methods which contain a single match expression should be declared in the following way:

```
def sum(ls: List[Int]): Int = ls match {
  case hd :: tail => hd + sum(tail)
  case Nil => 0
}
```

Comment: My OP specifically stated not to provide an opinion,  and instead to provide a reference to canonical style (if such exists).

Comment: I've added the citation

Comment: OK, your update to the question is better. Though, please change the wording of "I would .."  which was explicitly requested not to be used in the OP.

Comment: Flipped around for greater authoritativeness

Comment: OK, I had added the specifics to my OP (as opposed to adding another answer). In any case I will award. Pls consider an upvote.

Comment: The documentation has changed maybe? It does now say to *never* use curly braces for case.

Comment: Yeah, my style has evolved to that as well, mostly to match the idiom of using a partial function with one `case` to unpack an object. At the end of the day, I don't think it matters.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the same/next line for the curly brace the [Style Guide is explicit](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/nested-blocks.html#curly_braces) on that as well:

> Opening curly braces ({) must be on the same line as the declaration
>   they represent:

```
def foo = {   
  ...
}
```

> Technically, Scala’s parser does support GNU-style notation with
>   opening braces on the line following the declaration. However, the
>   parser is not terribly predictable when dealing with this style due to
>   the way in which semi-colon inference is implemented. Many headaches
>   will be saved by simply following the curly brace convention
>   demonstrated above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for participating. Actually my comment was wrt *Java* and the Sun style for its JDK, not Scala. Agreed: scala does not like braces on next line (and neither do I personally so that is a bonus).